# SQL Log for connection issues

Tags: sql-server-2008

Users get a connection error while using the application. It happens randomly and if they try a second later it's up and running.
At the same time, it's also happened to me using SQL Server Manager, I suddenly can't connect anymore to the database for a couple of seconds, then try again and bingo it's running.

My guessing is the connection to the server drops every now and then for little intervals of time.  When I talked about this to the IT people they say they need a proper report with dates and stuff in order to know if it's a server problem, user problem, etc.

So what I'd like to do is to create some sort of log indicating when I can't reach the server.
Do you people have any suggestion on the best way for accomplishing so?
All I can think of is a dts running every X seconds to just know if it was able to reach the desired server.

I should add that we're currently working on a, let's say new server, so it's not crowded with databases... The point about this is the server could actually be dropping (not so many users yet to scream at the IT team)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service was dropping that would be in the sql server log. If the server the DBMS is installed on was having problems, that would be in it's logs e.g. event viewer.
A number of clients having connection problems sounds like a network fault to me and you are being given the run around by your admin people. You could write something to keep connecting an log the result. Note this should alreday be built in to yoyr applicatiin logs! How many places are you going to install it though? How often is it going to run? How much of an impact is something like that going to affect the underlying problem...

Given you can rule out the dbms and server it's on suffering from something obvious, e.g, bad network card / driver, first thing I'd look at was topology. Are all the machines in one network segment, go through one switch etc.

Comment: Thanks for the imput, users run the application from different cities/buildings. The server is located here 2 floors above me but the IT people is not being that helpull or they are extremely busy. Either way I need to show them what's going on. I also believe it's a network problem... So, some local dts trying to reach the server and logging the result isn't a bad idea? I'd be doing that for a couple of days on 2 or 3 machines just to check if that's the case. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a horrible idea and it might show something. Bear in mind though if you are talkimng seconds the monitoring will increase the load on the system and could exacerbate the issue.